# Resolving Names From an Enum Inside a Class Without Qualification

Tags: c++, enums, using

Consider the following:

```
class Class { public:
  enum Enum {
    FOO, BAR
  };
};

void routine(void) {
  int x = Class::Enum::FOO;  //Option 1

  int y = Class::FOO;        //Option 2

  using Alias = Class::Enum; //Option 3
  int z = Alias::FOO;

  using Class::Enum;         //Option 4 (line 15)
  int w = FOO;
}
```

**Option 1** is full qualification.

C++ also allows **Option 2**.

**Option 4** as written will fail; g++ tells me:

```
15 : error: using declaration cannot refer to class member
using Class::Enum;
~~~~~~~^
15 : note: use an alias declaration instead
using Class::Enum;
^
```

before barfing on the `int w = FOO;` line following it.

I presume what g++ is suggesting is something like **Option 3**.  Unfortunately, this still requires a qualification, which is obnoxious.

My question: **Is there a way to get the `int w = FOO;` line to compile by fixing the line above it somehow?  If not, why not?  If yes, explain.**

Comment: Use a `enum class` with the current standard.

Comment: You are mixing "enum Enumeration" and ""enum class Enumeration" (C++11), which are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

class Class { public:
    enum Enum {
        FOO, BAR
    };
};

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    int x = Class::Enum::FOO;  //Option 1
    cout << x << endl;

    int y = Class::FOO;        //Option 2
    cout << y << endl;

    using Alias = Class::Enum; //Option 3
    int z = Alias::FOO;
    cout << z << endl;

    static constexpr auto FOO = Class::FOO;         //Option 4 (line 15)
    int w = FOO;
    cout << w << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Option 1 has been standardized in C++11, IIRC

Comment: As far as I can tell, the proposal for scoped enums comes from MS, that probably explains why option 1 is portable now.

Comment: @dyp ah, thanks for that. I wondered why it compiled on clang :-)

Comment: Have a +1; this certainly does it. But . . . is there a way without having to list each enum member separately? I have a lot.

Comment: You could define the enum in a namespace rather than a class. Other than that, I'm afraid not. The purpose of defining enum a in a class is to enforce the scope :)

Comment: "error: 'Class::Enum' is not a namespace" on option 4.

Comment: @Component10 you will need to set the compile flag -std=c++11?

Comment: @RichardHodges I tried it on both C++11 and C++14 (cpp.sh) Failed on both.

Comment: @Component10 I've just re-tested it and you're right. But when I compile it against clang 3.8 (judging by the date, this is what I would have used to test it) it compiles.

I'll update in light of this

Comment: @RichardHodges I'll be honest, I am not sure whether it should fail compilation or not, or why, but would assume that as failing occurs on a more modern compiler (GCC 4.9.2) it's probably safe to assume that failing is correct behavior. Probably.